# Where do I go - plastic faucet seat broken

Tags: plumbing

[image]

[image]

The first picture shows what I started with. 
The second shows what I have now.

I'm trying to install a Gerber bath/shower remodeling kit. I've gotten stuck on the seat removal. The seat rim broke off a little bit every time I tried to take it out.  I've tried making a groove with a hot screwdriver - no go. What are my options here?

Comment: Thank you - but it looks like just the plastic left inside the threads at this point, doesn't it?  (I'm just a DIY'er so I don't know exactly what I'm looking at.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drill holes 180 degrees across from each other, you want the holes as large as possible without hitting the brass threads. Now use a large screwdriver or small chisel to unscrew it. If it breaks then just dig out the pieces with a pick. Turn the water on afterwords to blow out any debris.